# How to set all elements in ul tag be same max width (with words wrap)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

So I have a list with buttons like:

```
<ul>
<li><FORM><INPUT type="button" value="some page!" onClick="window.open('http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm','jwinopen','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100')"></FORM></li>
<li><FORM><INPUT type="button" value="other page!" onClick="window.open('http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/samples_actionscript.html','samples_actionscript','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=400,screenY=100')"></FORM></li>
</ul>
```

I want all buttons to be size of max button and have some word wrap. How to do such thing? (IE6, firefox)

Comment: Do you need them to be in different <form>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started:

```
input[type="button"], .ieButton {
    max-width: 150px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
 }
```

but IE6 doesn;t recognise the css selector, so you ould give each buton a class 'ieButton and make bie6 specific css (odn't have a pc nearby, so i can't check ie for you)

Comment: IE 6 is just too old and senile to recognize it :)

Comment: generaly it is not 100% what was requested but works for me=)

Answer (score 2):

using css

```
ul > li > form input {width: 42px}
```

in this form will match all descendant `<input>s`